# KeyError in channel information when creating a dataset using an API with Python

Tags: python, json, rest, api, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataset retrieved from an API and here I'm getting this below error:

channels_list.append([JSONContent[u'timestamp'], JSONContent[u'name'], JSONContent[u'value']])
KeyError: u'timestamp'

Data retrieved from the JSON API looks like this:

{u'timestamp': 1550846387, u'name':XXXXXX', u'value': 42.50362770491802}

Here's my code for creating the dataset:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


#List of channels to access
channels = ["XXXXXX"]

channels_list = []
#For each channel, access its information through its API
for channel in channels:
    JSONContent = requests.get("http://localhost:8090/rest/datapoint/" + channel).json()
    channels_list.append([JSONContent[u'timestamp'], JSONContent[u'name'], JSONContent[u'value']])

dataset = pd.DataFrame(channels_list)
dataset.sample(5)
dataset.to_csv('dataset.csv', sep='\t')
```

If anyone can help me give an advice it would be great. If you can't tell, I haven't worked much with JSON data before.

Comment: is `u'name':XXXXXX'` what you get? if so, you'll need to work out to have `XXXXXX'` as `"XXXXXX'"`. That single 1 quote is throwing off the syntax

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I actually get is something like this, {u'timestamp': 1551179150, u'name': u'XXXXXXX', u'value': 41.84397459016393}.   Anyhow using double quotations didn't help me. Any thoughts?